# Why isn't my array surrounding each word with double quotes?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I have the following PHP code which returns an array `$words` that contains all of the words from column `SimplifyingFractionsQuestions` in MySql database:

```
<?php
   $data5 = $db->query("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT SimplifyingFractionsQuestions ORDER BY rand()) as SimplifyingFractionsQuestions FROM (SELECT SimplifyingFractionsQuestions FROM answers WHERE user_id=$id AND SimplifyingFractionsQuestions LIKE 's%') AS SimplifyingFractionsQuestions ")->fetch_assoc();
$selector= $data5['SimplifyingFractionsQuestions'];
$words = explode(" ", $selector);
?>
```

In addition, I have the following Jquery, which adds a new class `ClassHide` with unique CSS properties to every class found within that array

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function () {

var arr = <?php echo json_encode($words); ?>;

jQuery.each( arr, function( i, val ) {
  $( "." + val ).addClass("ClassHide");

});

});
</script>
```

The source shows, however, that this returns:

```
var arr = ["Question 1, Question 2, Question 3"]
```

so it will only add the class `ClassHide` to a div with class `Question 1, Question 2, Question 3`

I need it to return

```
var arr = ["Question 1", "Question 2", "Question 3"]
```

so it will add the class `ClassHide` to a div with class `Question 1` or `Question 2` or `Question 3`

Comment: just remove your group_concat and add group by in your select query it will return more than one row ..using foreach loop build your expected array

Comment: @ArunpandianM Thank you for the suggest. Someone else said that this won't work with `json_encode()`  Do you think I should try changing that, as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT # 2**

Before seeing the data, I thought this was the problem, but it seems `json_encode()` *will* do the job - but my comment remains, the Javascript line should still be terminated with a semicolon.

---

`json_encode()` isn't going to do that.  You want to do something like

```
var arr = [<?php    // leading '[' starts the array definition
    $sep='';
    foreach ($words as $word)
    {
        echo $sep.'"'.$word.'"';
        $sep=',';
    } ?>];  // trailing ']' ends the array, don't forget the semicolon!
```

**EDIT # 1**

This line

```
$words = explode(" ", $selector);
```

is going to try to break the contents of `$selector` into array elements, separating the string at space (`" "`) characters.  Since `$selector` doesn't have any spaces in it, `$words` is going to be exactly the same as `$selector`, you need to `explode(',', $selector)`

***N.B.*** You should use single-quoted strings for static string values, rather than double-quoted ones, so that the PHP interpreter doesn't have to parse the contents of the static string.  (faster, less processing overhead, better...)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion; seems to be a good direction to head, but source shows that it still returns the same array `var arr = ["Question 1, Question 2, Question 3"]`

Comment: What do the PHP variables `$selector` and `$words` contain?  i.e., `var_dump(...)` each of them

Comment: `$selector` var_dump: `string(112) "SimplifyingFractionsTres,SimplifyingFractions1,SimplifyingFractions3,SimplifyingFractions2,SimplifyingFractions4"`

Comment: `$words` var_dump: `array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(112) "SimplifyingFractions4,SimplifyingFractions1,SimplifyingFractionsTres,SimplifyingFractions2,SimplifyingFractions3"
}`

Comment: @Snoops So what does that tell you? `$data5['SimplifyingFractionsQuestions'];` does not contain any spaces. Therefor exploding it with a space character won't work. Explode it with a comma character instead.

Comment: @icecub Ahhhhhhhhhhh. Didn't even think about that (clearly ha) thanks so much

Comment: @icecub If you want to add that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: see my edits - I answered that as well - I was typing when @icecub made his comment

Comment: @Snoops Don't. Accept this answer. FKEinternet explains the same and he has put more than enough efford in this answer to deserve it.

Comment: @FKEinternet icecub was right - it was a matter of using the wrong separator; once I change that, `json_encode` still works

Comment: @icecub It wasn't a matter of `json_encode`, though; the code in the original post works when I use the comma as the separator rather than the space

Comment: Your explode statement should be something like $words = explode(',', $statement); since the string is seperated by a comma not a space

Comment: @icecub FKEinternet clarified; I accepted his answer. Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: @Snoops Then give FKEinternet a chance to edit his answer to correct it. If he didn't request you to `var_dump()` I wouldn't have known the issue either. I have more than enough reputation. Let him have this one. He earned it :)

Comment: Glad to help :)  I'm also glad to hear that `json_encode()` did the job, I wasn't expecting that - we all learn something new every day ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
<?php
   $data5 = $db->query("SELECT DISTINCT SimplifyingFractionsQuestions as SimplifyingFractionsQuestions FROM (SELECT SimplifyingFractionsQuestions FROM answers WHERE user_id=$id AND SimplifyingFractionsQuestions LIKE 's%') AS SimplifyingFractionsQuestions ORDER BY RAND() ")->fetch_assoc();
$selector= $data5['SimplifyingFractionsQuestions'];
foreach($data5['SimplifyingFractionsQuestions'] as $ques){
           $questionarray[] = $ques;
}
  ?>
```

and in your jquery

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function () {


jQuery.each( <?= $questionarray ?>, function( i, val ) {
  $( "." + val ).addClass("ClassHide");

});

});
</script>
```

> Note : there is no need for `json_encode` if both the functions exist in
>   the same page or else pass it as string from php and decode it in
>   jquery with `JSON.parse`